# Hosting both WordPress and my own code under the same domain (GoDaddy)

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, godaddy-api

I've been using GoDaddy and it works great with hosting my own code and my WordPress sites. However, I want to use both WordPress and my own code under the same domain.

For example, I have the domain `www.hello-world.com` , I've linked my WordPress to the root so now Godaddy recognizes it as a "Basic Managed WordPress Websites". Now I want my standalone website to appear in  `www.hello-world.com/product1`

I notice that I can access phpadmin, but I can't find a cPanel or see a Files Manager linked to the managed WordPress site, so I can't drop my code in.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: This may have to do with the way the WordPress rewrite works as your htaccess will rewrite anything that isn't a directory of file to index.php in the root. I take you are using url rewriting for the subdirectory too ?

Comment: The htaccess huh? I haven't really looked into that so it might be worth checking. I'm actually not very familiar with all this, including url rewriting... so I'm open to trying that method out

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! So I hope to share it with anyone who's looking for the answer too :)

Go to `My Products > Manage (the WordPress site you want) > Tools > File Browser`

and simply create a new folder under the root folder to create a new endpoint, now you can drop your code in!

Comment: Ah, I taught you already created the subdirectory with the PHP in it. As long as your custom code does not use URL rewriting it should be fine.